# Where does everipedia store all of its data? What parts are centralized?

Tags: storage, everipedia

Everipedia stores large amounts of data like wikipedia. Where is it stored? And what parts are centralized?

Answer (score 2):

Everipedia's data is stored using IPFS which is a distributed free IP based file system. Anyone can participate in IPFS and help strengthen the network in general.

Read more about the Everipedia's team explanation about it [in this interview](https://medium.com/@nalamsubash/week-2-questions-answered-by-everipedia-team-cb1d70480df) or on their official [whitepaper](https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/everipedia-whitepaper/).